# The best approach to creating EXT4 partitions copy (without need of restoring them later)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

Currently, I have 2 * 2TB SSDs in my PC:

- First one has only one NTFS partition with Windows.
- Second one has several partitions: 1 TB NTFS used by Windows and 4 partitions with Linux: two big EXT4 partitions with data, one swap and one with GRUB bootloader.
  I need to prepare brand new Linux installation and clear those 2 big Linux partitions, but I want to copy them, so I will be able to access some old data.

**What is the best approach to prepare copy of those two EXT4 partitions, so I can access them later?** I don't really need to restore working system partitions from those copies, I just need to access files, although currently I'm unable to decide which files I need and which I don't. I have another empty disk with enough space to contain all of these. I wish to save as much space as possible, but also I don't want to wait forever to unpack dense archives.

I was thinking about 3 solutions:

- Use some tool that would create single file from each partition. But is this possible to access files within those copies without restoring whole parition from them?
- Byte-by-byte copy of those partitions. But won't it waste a lot of space on another disk? There is a lot of free space on those partitions.
- Just use some file manager to copy all exisiting files into prepared directory on another disk, without creating any special partitions. Are there some downsides of that solution, if I don't need to restore those partitions later?

Comment: With Linux Mint, I'd first use the ***disks*** utility to shrink the partition, then use ***fsarchiver*** to back it up, and restore it as required. Or perhaps back it up before shrinking if that was more convenient. Note that ***fsarchiver*** allows you to exclude any specific folders or files that you *know* you don't need (which probably includes, for example, multiple Linux kernel files).

Comment: I would love to use that tool, but if I read correctly, I need to fully restore fsarchiver  backup file somewhere before accessing contained files, which is not very usefull in my case, unofrtunelly.

Comment: Note: Linux can easily mount a file that is a copy of a partition, but not if it's compressed.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you don’t need an exact copy of the on-disk layout of blocks, and that this is intended to be a read-only copy, my tool of choice would be SquashFS.

SquashFS is, as the name implies, a filesystem, but aside from it being possible to mount it directly as such on Linux, it’s better thought of as a *really* fancy archive format. In addition to storing files it:

- Compresses them using an algorithm of choice (or optionally none at all).
- Compresses it’s own internal data structures independently of the files (this gets better compression ratios on average because you don’t end up with the compressor state being polluted from previous files/metadata).
- Detects duplicate files and stores only one copy of the data with multiple hardlinks.
- Sanely handles sparse files, only storing actual data.
- Has special handling to avoid wasting space with partial blocks at the end of files.
- Stores *full* UNIX permissions and ownership.
- Stores extended attributes, including support for POSIX ACLs, SELinux security contexts, and other such useful things.
- Allows full random access to files (no need to parse most of the filesystem/archive just to get a file near the end).

This makes it uniquely suited to the type of use case you describe.

Most Linux systems have the required tooling to create SquashFS images available in a package called `squashfs-tools`. Accessing a SquashFS image once created can be done three different ways:

- Almost all major Linux distributions include a kernel driver for SquashFS, letting you treat a SquashFS image as a regular filesystem (though if you use certain compression algorithms you will need a new enough kernel to read the image).
- The `squashfuse` package available for most Linux distributions will alternatively let you mount the image as a filesystem using FUSE, meaning you don’t need root access (but providing slightly worse performance).
- `squashfs-tools` provides a command called `unsquashfs` which can be used to list or extract individual files just like you would with most other archive formats.

Comment: Sounds promising, possibility of mounting such a file could save me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @serwus FWIW, there are ways to mount most common archive formats as filesystems as well (mostly the `archivemount` package, which can do so for any format supported by libarchive). I recommend SquashFS specifically over those though because it’s better at saving space in most real-world usage, and does far better for random access.

Answer (score 5):

> but also I don't want to wait forever to unpack dense archives.

Don't use Tar as the archive format then. Most other archive formats (7z, rar, zip) are non-"dense" by default and allow individual files to be extracted directly, without any significant loss in compression efficiency.

> Use some tool that would create single file from each partition. But is this possible to access files within those copies without restoring whole parition from them?

Yes, in exactly the same way as if reading from an actual partition. There is nothing fundamentally different in accessing files between the two.

So when you have a file containing the ext4 image:

- On Linux, files containing a filesystem can be attached to a "loop device" which then can be mounted just like a partition. (It even supports fstrim, allowing you to trim the "empty" space of the inner filesystem so that it occupies no space in the outer filesystem, as long as the latter supports sparse files.)

  Most other systems support mounting file-backed filesystems; even Windows has a limited form that supports ISO and VHD formats (though that doesn't help you with ext4, but Disk2vhd would be the tool of choice for NTFS disks).
- On Windows, the 7-zip archiver supports ext4 like if it was an archive format, so you can open ext4 images and browse the files inside.

(There is very little difference between archives and filesystems – it's all about how the data inside is structured, i.e. does it have a central index that allows seeking through, does it use a form of compression that is non-seekable. For example, when accessing something in a tar.gz archive you need to "extract" all of it due to its tape-oriented structure that has no central index and because its compression is applied to the whole archive at once, but you don't have to do that with zip/rar/7z archives because they compress each item individually.)

> Byte-by-byte copy of those partitions. But won't it waste a lot of space on another disk? There is a lot of free space on those partitions.

Most filesystems support "sparse" files, where a long run of NUL bytes can just be marked as a "hole" and not stored on disk. There are partition clone tools that understand the filesystem structure and skip copying the areas that the filesystem indicates as empty, creating a sparse image file that doesn't occupy its full size. For NTFS such a tool would be ntfsclone, for ext4 and btrfs and others – partclone.

(Linux "loop devices" can even turn a full-size image into a sparse image after cloning, as long as you can fit the full image at first.)

There are also image formats that track the "holes" internally – they're used by VMs to store the virtual machine disk images. VHD/VHDX is one such format; if you created an NTFS image using Disk2vhd into a VHD file, it would only occupy as much space as the data inside, and it could be opened by double-clicking it.

Comment: 7z and rar also support "solid" archives where one compression stream contains multiple files, like tar.gz, allowing them to find redundancy between multiple small files.  (If you have a lot of very similar smallish files, there actually *are* big losses in `.zip` (or gzip each file separately) vs. `tar.gz` or `tar.zstd` or `7z`.)  I don't see it in the man page, but hopefully `7z` (or other archivers for that format?) know how to batch files in groups of at least 16 MiB or 1 GiB or something, so random access isn't too bad, while also still getting most of the benefit of solid archives.

Comment: Hmm, how complicated is this? From my understanding, `dd` is useless in that case, because it copies a free space as well. I suppose I would need to use live instance of Linux, so I can work on unmounted partitions and then use some other tool, like gnome-disk-utility?

Comment: Maybe `sudo cp --sparse=always IN OUT`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Both 7z and rar support "solid blocks" that limit solid groups by size sum, or number of files, or by file extension. 7z site does not mention, but its help file and this page does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression#Costs

Comment: A cheap hack to make sure your filesystem is full of zero bytes in the unused spaces is to fill it up by copying a file full of zero bytes until it's full.